# Is Angular Js compulsion for Node Js?

Tags: html, angularjs, node.js

Is angular js required in the front end for node ? Can be it done with just html instead of angular?

Comment: No it's not required. `NODE` and `Angular` are two different creatures. Yes, you can use plain HTML and JS instead of angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, AngularJs is a frontend MVW framework whereas Nodejs is a Server side technology.

You can use both together in your project or simply use one of them.It doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement to use Angular with nodejs. You can use whatever you want, including plain raw HTML.

Answer (score 0):

of course no. you may even have no font-end at all. just provides pure api for mobile, iot, web ...

Answer (score -1):

Is Angular Js compulsion for Node Js?

Not at all.

Can be it done with just html instead of angular?

Definitely.

It is very common to use a web application framework like Express, Sails, Hapi or Koa (there are many more).